# How to know Windows Store app was pre-installed

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I'd like to know from my Windows 8 app whether it was pre-installed or downloaded from the Windows Store. In WP8, this is possible by checking the "IsApplicationPreInstalled" property in [Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties).

Is there an equivalent in .NET WinRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from Microsoft: as of today (June 2014), this is not possible.

Here's the thread with the answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94975106-e0f1-4f35-a530-62d6ec434d50/how-to-know-app-was-preinstalled?forum=winappswithcsharp